# Rearranging values from a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2012, self-taught so sorry for any errors/mistakes.

I have a table that I had pivot and the resulting table has null values like so:

```
Pepsi    Coke    Gatorade
--------------------------
Vanilla  NULL    NULL
Cherry   NULL    NULL
NULL     Vanilla NULL
NULL     Cherry  NULL
NULL     NULL    Lime
NULL     NULL    Fruit Punch
NULL     NULL    Grape
```

My question is if there is a way to rearrange the table so that the rows that are not null show up at the top of their respective columns in such a way so that if another user was to add a different type of drink, such as water, that the query would be to automatically sort the newly added column. If this cannot be accomplished then an alternative suggestion would be appreciated.

An example of the desired result would be like so:

```
Pepsi    Coke    Gatorade
------------------------------
Vanilla  Vanilla Lime
Cherry   Cherry  Fruit Punch
NULL     NULL    Grape
```

I have tried doing a series of outer joins from the FROM clause however, I cannot figure out a way to generate the results without explicitly calling the columns and/or table names.

```
select distinct t1.Pepsi, t2.Coke from 
(select 
    #test.Pepsi as Pepsi, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Pepsi) r 
 from #test
 where Pepsi is not null) as t1

full outer join

(select 
    #test.Coke as Coke, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Coke) r 
 from #test 
 where Coke is not null) as t2

on t1.r=t2.r
```

The original table looks like so:

```
Drink    Type     Price   Location  etc
Coke     Vanilla 
Coke     Cherry
Gatorade Lime
Gatorade Grape
.
.
.
Pepsi    Cherry
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Drink] varchar(max), [Type] varchar(max), [Price] money )

INSERT @t
([Drink],[Type])
VALUES
('Coke','Vanilla'),
('Coke','Cherry'),
('Gatorade','Lime'),
('Gatorade','Grape'),
('Gatorade','Fruit Punch'),
('Pepsi','Vanilla'),
('Pepsi','Cherry')

;WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    [Drink],[Type],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Drink] ORDER BY [Type] DESC) rn
  FROM @t
)
SELECT [Pepsi],[Coke],[Gatorade]
FROM t
PIVOT(MAX([Type]) FOR [Drink] IN ([Pepsi],[Coke],[Gatorade])) p
```

Comment: If you want to add additional [Drink] values as additional columns in the output, search for "Dynamic Pivot".  Be warned that chances are high that SQL is not the best tool you have for this operation.